# Batch File Variables Not Working how they should

Tags: file, variables, batch-file

I am running this code:

```
@echo off
set /a var=0001
:start
if %var% == 10 set %var5%=00
if %var% == 100 set %var5%=0
if %var% == 1000 set %var5%=
if %var% == 9999 pause
set /a var=%var5%%var%+1
set var2=STRING %VAR%
set var3=ENTER
set var4=DELAY 1000
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
echo %var4%
@echo %var2%>> inject.txt
@echo %var3%>> inject.txt
@echo %var4%>> inject.txt
goto start
```

Which I made to generate a text file for a brute forcer that runs on a Usb rubber ducky. But, the if %var% == 10 set %var5%=00    Does not work. When it reaches 10, 100, or 1000 it does not add the 0000 to the beginning of the number. Please help, I'm using this for a friend that had his steam account hacked, and he needs to crack the 4 digit pin for the "parental controls"

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the %%around var5 in the set statement. You use the %% syntax only to read the value of an env var, not to assign.

Comment: Thanks but, now when I run it, it still does not work, but it says Invalid numerical number

Answer (score 0):

The value assigned by `set /a` will suppresss leading zeroes; the hard way here is to use strings.

The easy way is this:

```
set /a var=10000
:loop
set "anothervar=%var:~-4%"
echo %anothervar%
set /a var+=1
if %var% lss 20000 goto loop
```